# php error Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Tags: php-errors, codeigniter, files

Got an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 345
```

I do not have a helpers folder in my main directory but I have one in my codeigniter > system and the file form_helper.php exists there.

Is the path to CI needing updated?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a bit more information to what you are doing?

e.g. are you creating an add-on and calling form open? Or are you using a template tag that shows a form? The issue is (if you look at line 345 form_helper) that you/it is trying to pass an array in a $key or $val to output a form_select option="" html tag.

Comment: sorry php version error